# .Net Core 3.1 Json serialization of EdmModel

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

I encountered an issue but I'm not sure if it's a bug or a known behaviour (can't find anything).

So we use the Orleans project and in one of our grain in the state we store an EdmModel. The issue is that Orleans raise an error during the serialization of the EdmModel (using Newtonsoft). So I was like, ok, let's find out what I've done wrong when buidling the Edm (it's constructed "by hand" because we don't have the models (created by users)).

To check what was happening I try to serialize the Edm myself and encountered the following :

```
Self referencing loop detected for property 'DeclaringType' with type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmEntityType'. Path 'SchemaElements[0].DeclaredKey[0]'.
```

So I was like, ok. I've done something bad and it's why the serialisation is not working, But after commenting my code to narrow the issue, I was left with the following :

```
        var model = new EdmModel();

        try
        {
            var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var poney = 1;
        }

        try
        {
            var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var poney = 2;
        }
```

And it's still raising an error.

```
Self referencing loop detected for property 'Model' with type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.Csdl.CsdlSemantics.CsdlSemanticsModel'. Path 'ReferencedModels[1].SchemaElements[0]'
```

And for the second try catch an OutOfMemory.

So I'm asking if there is a way to serialize an EdmModel to Json ? Because if it is what we can do is storing the EdmModel as string in the state of the grain and making serializaion/deserialization in the Getter/Settter.

Or maybe with Xml?

Thanks a lot for the help and the inputs :)

Comment: Hi @S.Martignier, Did you use Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel? What is the version of  `Microsoft.Data.Edm`? It works well and do not have any errors in my asp.net core 3.1 project.

Comment: I'm using the ```Microsoft.OData.Edm``` from the assembly (nugget) ```Microsoft.OData.Edm``` in version 7.8.3.0

Comment: With `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` the problem seems to be that you really are just running out of memory because of the sheer quantity of stuff returned by  [`EdmModelBase.ReferencedModels`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.edm.edmmodelbase.referencedmodels).  I was able to (eventually) get a successful serialization by also setting `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/bFRTuG.  You probably should be able to serialize directly to a file stream as well with or without `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`

Comment: `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` seems to help because the same schema elements are references from multiple locations.  But I suspect that `PreserveReferencesHandling.Arrays` will not help because `CsdlSemanticsModel` always manufactures and returns new enumerables for its `IEnumerable<T>` properties, as shown in the [reference source](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/master/src/Microsoft.OData.Edm/Csdl/Semantics/CsdlSemanticsModel.cs).

Comment: So, close as "Not Reproducible"?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the investigation and the fiddle :)
And I think that you are right